# Blender how to install package conveniently

Tags: python

```
>>> import imutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'

>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

>>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'
```

all packages installed on my system python, but not found why?

Comment: It is my understanding that the Windows version of blender (and maybe some others) comes with its own bundled Python which will have a separate package location. I'm not sure how you would go about installing packages for the bundled python or get it to use your system python though.

Comment: @Gorgious I found it might answered my question, but I got another very serious problem, I installed the package, but can not import,,,, only this one, other package can import normally https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248916/blender-python-installed-dlib-but-can-not-import-from-blender

Comment: More weired, I using system terminal enter blender's python, it can import, but not work inside blender GUI python promot.