# Blender python installed dlib but can not import from blender

Tags: python, scripting

[image]

[image]

This is really weird, I have installed, and I have restarted Blender, but Just can not import dlib from Blender.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Is the package installed on your global python environment or in the blender folder ? eg Blender/3.0/python/lib

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488685

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.codeplastic.com/2019/03/12/how-to-install-python-modules-in-blender/) explains how to do the install, in case you're not familiar with installing in multiple python instances.